# Trying to create program that compares user-input strings to a set of predefined input strings in C

Tags: c, string, user-input

I'm currently working on a program that will compare a set of input strings to a user input. The only condition is I'm not allowed to use built-in string operations; I must code them all from scratch.

The input strings is an array of strings like so:

```
char *input_strings[] = { 
    "Hello", "What is your name?", "How are you?", "Bye"
};
```

What I currently have is a bunch of functions:

1) uppercheck, which checks if a value is uppercase or not:

```
int uppercheck(int c){
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}
```

2) lowercase, which converts a value to lowercase:

```
int lowercase(int c){
    if (uppercheck(c)){
        c + 0x20;
    }
    else{
        c;
    }
}
```

3) compstr, which compares two lowercase strings:

```
int result;
int compstr(char str1[], char str2[]){
    for(int i = 0; str1[i]; i++){
        if (lowercase(str1[i]) == lowercase(str2[i])){
            result = 1;
        }
        else{
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The latter part of my code checks if the user string is equal to each entry in the input_strings array, like so:

```
char input[100]; // user input string
while (1) // infinite loop
{ 
    //Get the input string
    printf("> ");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    // comparing strings:

    //3 base input conditions:
    if (compstr(input_strings[0], input) == 1)
    {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
    else if (compstr(input_strings[1], input) == 1)
    {
        printf("My name is Name\n");
    }
    else if (compstr(input_strings[2], input) == 1)
    {
        printf("I am fine\n");
    }
    //exit condition:
    else if (compstr(input_strings[3], input) == 1) 
    {
        printf("Bye\n"); 
        break;
    }
    //invalid input:
    else 
    {   
        printf("I do not understand\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

My problem is that the program will output "Hello" for ANY input, even when there's no input at all. I thought that the compare function would make sure the two strings are identical, but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to approach it from here. Sorry if I overdid the code but I figured I'd add as much info as possible. Any help would be heavily appreciated!

Comment: Your function (3) will return 1 for every two strings with the same first character

Comment: Instead of a multi-pass solution, you may want to do a single-pass where you have a lookup table to do lower-case conversion and then compare the remapped values from string A and B to see if they're equal. Move character by character, and stop if the lengths mismatch or the values mismatch.

Comment: I'd recommend making a function to get the length, and a function to lowercase to reduce the amount of repeated code and to make things clearer for yourself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. does the for loop not iterate over the entire string? Or does return stop the loop from fully iterating? I'm quite new to C so I'm trying to figure out these smaller things.

Comment: This is what `return` does - returns from the function as soon as encountered.

Comment: Comparing the lengths before comparing the data means you have to scan the whole of each string at least once, whereas simply looking at the first character may tell you that the two strings cannot be equal.  Similarly, the case-conversion should only be done "as needed".  Therefore, you'd do better with an algorithm that only scans the the data once, leaving the length to be resolved when you reach the end of one (or both) strings.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the character-type functions from `<ctype.h>`?  They're not string functions, so you nominally should be able to do so.  If so, use them: `isupper` and `tolower()` seem to be what you want — though you could speed things up by noting that `tolower()` only changes upper-case letters; anything else is passed through unchanged, so you don't need to test for upper-ness — just convert everything with `tolower()` and compare the results.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't use tolower unfortunately, which is why I coded the function myself. My original attempt tried creating individual functions to do everything, but I couldn't quite figure out how to impliment it all so I threw it into one big function. I'm not quite sure how to only scan the data itself without using strcmp, which (if available) would make this plenty easier.

Comment: It appears that you need to write a case-insensitive string compare — `stricmp()` on Windows and `strcasecmp()` on POSIX, IIRC.  Basically, you iterate over the characters of the string, case-converting each to the same case, and comparing the result. Can you use `inline`?  If so, write your own `isupper()` and `tolower()` functions inline: `static inline int za_isupper(int c) { return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'); }` and `static inline int za_tolower(int c) { return (za_isupper(c) ? c + 0x20 : c); }` and use those (use the `za_tolower()` in the main code). If you can't use `inline`, simply omit it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much for this! It definitely condenses things a lot. I did what you said and created a for loop to compare them, however it seems like I'm getting a new error; no matter what I enter for my input, I always get out "Hello". Before I was at least getting all 4 conditions, it just was dependent on length and not the data in the string. I'm not sure where to proceed with this, could it be the output ifs that are causing issues?

Comment: It's going to be hard to say without seeing the revised code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry for the silence, been a bit busy. I edited to reflect the new code I've been experimenting with, I'm getting the same error I was getting yesterday (where no matter what the input is, I get "Hello" as my output).

Answer (score 1):

In conclusion, you forgot to write `return` in the `lowercase` function and you didn't put a `break;` after `result = 0;` and the code should work fine.

**Explanation:**

There is only one place in your code that prints `Hello` so we know that the expression `printf("Hello\n")` is being executed in every loop. This means that the `if` statement immediately above this expression is being evaluated to `true` every time, which can only happen if the function `compstr()` always returns a `1` regardless of what `input` is. Now, let's dive into the `compstr()` function and see where the `1` comes from.

Well, the variable `result` is set to `1` if `lowercase(str1[i])` is equal to `lowercase(str2[i])`. Okay, so our problem is that `lowercase(str1[i])` is always the same as `lowercase(str2[i])`. Check your `lowercase()` function. You did not write any return statement in the function at all, and so it will always return a garbage number regardless of what `c` is. Basically, all you have to do is change `c + 0x20;` to `return c + 0x20;` and `c;` to `return c;`. That's it. Very simple mistake.

Now, the much bigger problem is that you do not have a break statement after you assign `result = 0;` in the `compstr()` function like this:

```c
...
        else{
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
...
```

Why is this break important? Well, it is only relevant when `str1` is longer than `str2`. See, the terminating condition for your `for` loop involves `str1` only, and so even when we reach the last character in `str2`, we still keep looping if `str1` is longer than `str2`. Let's look at an example scenario. Let's run the program and type `Hello`. The program stores `Hello` in `input` like this `input = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', ...}`, and then checks with the first input condition with `compstr()` and prints `Hello`. Now type `Bye`. Now, the array `input` is `{'B', 'y', 'e', '\0', 'o', '\0', ...}`. Notice how the `o` from `Hello`, is still there? The `for` loop  in `compstr` will set `result` to `0` on the first character comparison which is fine but without the break, it will keep on looping even after comparing the last `e` in `Bye` because you are comparing it with `Hello` which has 5 characters, not 3. On the last loop, your `if` statement will compare the 5th character of `Hello` and 5th character of `Bye`, which is the letter `o` for both. and so `result` is set to `1` in the end of the loop and so the `compstr` function returns `1` and then the program prints `Hello` instead of `Bye`, even though you typed `Bye`, because `Bye` is shorter than `Hello`. Try, `How are you?` and it will print `I am fine` normally, but now if you type `Hello` or `Bye`, you will still get `I am fine`, because `input` looks like this: `'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '?', '\0' ...`. The `e you?` at the end is garbage value from a few steps back when we stored `How are you?` in this very same `input` variable.